# Can I simulate/test the model of a robot I am designing to be 3d printed?

Tags: simulation, 3d-printing

I am currently working on the 3d model of a simple robot. However I have started to realize that some of the things/mechanisms might not work as I imagined.

So is there any way that I can import the obj file of this model somewhere, set things as rigid bodies and add set axles to rotate continuously and then see if the motion gets transferred to the desired places and things like that? I am looking for something simple.

I really apologize for this vague question but I have really no knowledge of mechanical engineering and don't understand many terms.

Comment: If you know the dynamic equations of your system, it is possible to simulate the output response of your robot given a set of input torque/force using matlab/octave. Common functions used are lsim() and lsode() or ode45().

Comment: you can do that with solidworks if you have the original solidwork design file.

Comment: @user123456098 I don't think I'm looking for a complete mathematical simulation. I am just trying to see if my model will work when 3d printed and assembled with all its mechanical components working as I visualize it. Plus, I have no idea what these dynamic equations are.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like what you describe in at least 2 softwares:

- Matlab/Simulink with the Simscape Multibody toolbox https://mathworks.com/help/sl3d/link-to-simulink-and-simmechanics-models.html
- inside Inventor from Autodesk  (eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__EjxKIsy9E )

There are many tutorials on the internet to assist you there. 
Unfortunately these two solutions rely
on very expensive piece of software, I am not aware of a free counterpart but it can exist. Also there are trial and student version of these software for free.

Answer (score 0):

There's some free software that can simulate some of the aspects of your case. Some are not easy as the paid ones.

Link to a free software that can simulate your case
http://www.hotint.org